# How can I sign a third party COM dll with strong name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, com, com+

All I need to create a WCF service that talks to third party com application. How do I sign this com with strong name so that I can Host this as a COM+ application .

Comment: COM+ doesn't know anything about strong names.  You have a different kind of problem. No idea what, this isn't documented well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a signed interop for the com DLL.

tlbimp yourcomdll.dll /keyfile:”mystrongnamekeyfile.snk” /namespace:yourcomdll /out:Interop.yourcomdll.dll

Comment: Done that, but when I try to put the dll into com+ ; it throws a message 'One or more files do not contain components or type libraries. These files cannot be installed.'

Comment: unfortunately my COM+ experience is limited.  Please post your solution if you find one.  Thanks!